# Online Multimedia Streaming and Two Way communication / Conference options

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, sip, voip, webrtc

I am about to restart an old project ([Open Source Video Chat](https://code.google.com/p/video-chat/)) Flex/PHP/Java. The code, released in 2010, had the capability of one-to-eight, two-way multimedia streaming and communication (conference call) and random video chat. I am about to re-start after four years without much info about the latest options. At this point I am looking towards Node.js and WebRTC but there are too many questions like:

- What about **Mac** and especially the **iOS** devices where **WebRTC
  and/or Flash is not an option**.
- How about Firewalls and other
  obstacles, maybe a native app is the way to go..

**Any suggestions? Does anyone have related experience, a good hint maybe?**

- On the server-side, while Node.js seems the fastest, it can be resource-hungry when hitting the millions. PHP and Java did pretty well but fell short at handling database connections (MySQL/Oracle) by killing the host server.

Any suggestion, idea, warning or advice is highly appreciated! ☀ Thank you!

Comment: Mac(OSX) would work fine with WebRTC as they have Chrome. iOS could have a native application written for it using the native api

Answer (score 1):

With all major Vendors [even Microsoft] ORTC / WebRTC is the way for Audio / Video communications. So your software can focus on WebRTC and gain good traction.

There are a lot of vendors who provide video / multimedia conferencing capabilities. The general peer to peer model or the MCU model to support larger groups. Some of the vendors that i remeber top of my head are erizo, jitsi on the open source side. There are also lot of WebRTC  vendors who provide the software to build communications platforms and they come in numerous languages. EasyRTC for eg is a Node.js implementation and there are other similar platforms.

So you will have to decide the value proposition of the software and compare it with these to determine its USP.